# How to render line plot with uncertainty in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I am wondering whether I can plot a graph in which I show a range of best and worst results using matplotlib. The result should look something like this:

[Image of the graph I want to replicate here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47OI.png)

You see the ranges around each point that specify what the best and worst measure is? This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the errorbar function does exactly what you want:
https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
# yerr can be a single number or an array with same length as x and y
# depending on whether you want it to be constant or changing
yerr = 1
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr)
plt.show()
```